# What do I need to connect a hard disk to my laptop via non powered eSata?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, esata

I'm looking at getting a hard disk for my laptop (OCZ Vertex 2 SSD) which I would like to connect via eSata.  My laptop has an eSata port, but it's not powered (Thinkpad T410).

I presume this means I need more than just an eSata to eSata cable as it needs power, so does this mean I need a caddy for the hard disk as well which will provide power to the drive, or do I need one of them eSata cables that has a USB attachment too?  I don't think the drive will come with a power supply.

I realise this seems simple but I can't find an obvious answer online.  Thanks for any assistance!

Ludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external eSATA [enclosure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0029Z9ULE) I'm using gets its power from a separate USB cable.

Depending on how many USB ports you have in your laptop, and how much you tend to use them, this could be an issue. Especially considering the tendency for USB extension hubs to be underpowered. If the enclosure isn't getting enough power, the drive will just be unavailable. If you go this route, be sure to disable all USB power saving options in windows, as that'll cause some fun & random issues.

What I really wish I'd done is to pick up a hot-swappable caddy to run the drive in the bay where the DVD drive currently sits (about $50 USD for my laptop). No power issues, no lost USB port.

(On a side note, if you want some fun, put the SSD in as the laptop's main drive and use the old SATA as the external data drive. Watching windows boot up in < 10 seconds is a hoot)

Comment: Thanks!  I'd ordered a Startech caddy with USB power.  Will see if it can get enough power from the hub.

Comment: It's initially for taking an image of a laoptop I need to send back, but will switch it to main drive once I'm confident the replacement isn't faulty and I'm confident enough to take the back off :).  I don't run Windows but Ubuntu on my SSD based machine at home boots in less than 5 seconds.  Can't really go back once you've got used to SSD.  Thanks.

Comment: I hear that. SSD pretty much ruins you for anything else.

Comment: Just for the record, that enclosure died after about a month. At least, the eSATA component did. eSATA might just be something I avoid at this point, reading some unfavorable things about it now.